# function works after two clicks instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a guessing game that uses a random number generator to assign a 'correct' box.
If the box that you guess is incorrect, I want it to fade out.

It does this, except I have to click it twice for it to fade.

On the first click, `incorrect();` is successfully called, and then only on the second click is `fade();` successfully called. i have 5 other functions with the same code as function one() that pertain to different boxes/divs and don't want to past the jquery 6 times.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT: here is a jsFiddle with more code to look at. Might make it easier to answer:** http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/

```
function correct() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You are correct!";
}

function incorrect() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, you are incorrect.";
}

function fade() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(temp2).click(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                "opacity": "0.25"
            },
                "slow");
        });
    });
}


function one() {
    temp2 = "#one";

    if (temp == 1) {
        correct();
    } else {
        fade();
        incorrect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `doc.ready` inside a function like that?

Comment: Do not use document.ready inside a function, that's wrong.

Comment: I put it in the function so I can call it when certain things are clicked. How do I do that without putting it in a function?

Comment: Could you post the full code?

Comment: Just move all the JavaScript code just before the closing `</body>` tag and you don't need `doc.ready` anymore.

Comment: Could you please show us html code or maybe a live example in jsFiddle?

Comment: hehe copy pasting without understanding is baaaaad :P

Comment: How do you make a jsFiddle example?

Comment: my jsFiddle is not working. And to be clear, I ONLY want the box to fade out if it was guessed incorrectly. I have 5 other boxes with essentially the same code as function one(). I don't wamt to copy and paste the jquery 6 times.

Comment: @user1157541, It doesn't matter, just share your jsFiddle example, at least we must see your html to answer your question correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have jQuery included in your page, why don't you use it,

First, use data attribute to store some info about box,

```
<div class="box" id="one" data-id="1">
<div class="box" id="two" data-id="2">
<div class="box" id="three" data-id="3">
...
```

You can directly add click event listener for all `div` elements which has a class as `box` like this,

```
$("div.box").click(function() {
      if (temp == $(this).data("id")) {
          correct();
      } else {
          $(this).animate({"opacity": "0.25"}, "slow");
          incorrect();
      }
  });
```

### [And here is the updated and working jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var temp2 = "#one";
function correct() {
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You are correct!";
} 

function incorrect() {
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, you are incorrect.";
}

function one() {

   if (temp == 1) {
     correct();
   } 
   else {
     incorrect();
   }
}

$(document).ready(function () {  
     $(temp2).click(function () {
         $(this).animate({
             "opacity": "0.25"
         },
             "slow");
      });
  });
```

First up you call jQuery's function when the document is ready, which means it is fully loaded.Second I have pulled out the temp2="#one" though that you easily be replaced as $("#one").click.
For the code to work fully, I need information on where you have defined temp.

Comment: Did you just take the jquery out of the fade function? or did you change more than that?

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle with more code for you to see, although for some reason the javascript isnt working at all on it. http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/

Answer (score 1):

Replace your fade function with:

```
function fade(elem) {
    $(elem).click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
}

function one() {
    temp2 = "#one";

    if (temp == 1) {
        correct();
    } else {
        fade(temp2);
        incorrect();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit this, because `temp2` is set in a function, so `temp2` will be undefined in `document.ready`.

Comment: Right, I sort of misunderstood the question the first time, but now I get it.

Comment: @user1157541 : You're going to have to pass `temp2` as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest trying to remove the $(document).ready wrapper. If your JavaScript is at the end of your body element, you won't need it. Either that or wrap your "one" method in the $(document).ready.